# How to make VS Code go to source instead of dist for workspaces?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, monorepo, npm-workspaces

I have a monorepo created with NPM workspaces. The structure is as follows:

```
- packages
-- common
--- src
---- components
-- app1
-- app2
```

`common` contains some common React components, which both `app1` and `app2` use.
To do that cross-workspace, we build `common`, and import from the built package as follows:

```
// inside app1
import { CommonComponent } from 'common/dist';

function App() {
  return <CommonComponent />;
}
```

In VS Code this causes an issue where Cmd + clicking `CommonComponent` here (`Go to Definition`) predictably sends me to `common/dist/src/components/CommonComponent.d.ts`. I would like to be sent to the original `common/src/components/CommonComponent.tsx` instead.

Likewise, inside `CommonComponent.tsx`, when Cmd + clicking the component definition, I am shown no usage results (since the one being used is the one from `dist`). I would like to be shown all the usages of the one from `dist` (make it a proxy, if you will).

I realize what I'm asking for is the definition of unexpected behavior, but given that this is a local package, I feel comfortable with it. This is something that seems to be possible in IntelliJ's Webstorm, and I would like this to also be possible in VS Code.

Edit 1:

The project has a root `.eslintrc` which other workspaces extend:

```json
{
    "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [
          ".ts",
          ".tsx",
          ".js"
        ]
      },
      "typescript": {
        "projects": [
          "packages/*/tsconfig.json",
          "packages/*/*/tsconfig.json"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "airbnb"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  rules: [...]
}
```

Every workspace also has the following `.tsconfig`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
}
```

Comment: Have you declared any eslint, babel, tsconfig, prettier etc in your root folder?

Comment: @SteveTomlin I have, there's a base .eslintrc which all the workspaces extend, and a basic tsconfig (and every workspace implements its own).

Comment: Share the code - because you can set an alias in both tsconfig and eslint

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I can't share my code here, it's company code, hence my high-level description.

Comment: there is nothing privacy or security about the eslint or tsconfig. The point is - thats where you declare your references. For tsconfig its paths, for eslint you can use a plugin - import/resolver, for babel  - module-resolver and so on.